# Jenkins throwing NPM err code 403 when publishing to Nexus Repo

Tags: docker, jenkins, nexus

I’m having this weird error when deploying to nexus.

```
npm i
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden: express@^4.16.3
```

Where the artifact at the end it changes from time to time (I mean, is not always express@^4.16.3)

Things I have checked so far.

I can login to Nexus through browser using the user and password that is defined on the upload.
I can login to Nexus repo through shell using the user and password defined on the upload.

I can upload the package using a local shell and using the same credentials.

During the execution, I did a curl -v repo-url and I get a correct response (so I assume I got network connectivity).

I have checked if was a proxy, and there was.
I deleted the proxy configuration
I changed to another proxy
I added a no proxy variable so I can except the FQDN of the Nexus URL Repo

I also checked if the package (in this case express@^4.16.3) exists on Nexus, and it does.

But in all cases I’m still getting the 403 error at the end.

To give a bit more of context.
This is using Jenkins.

And targetting a new nexus that I'm deploying.
If I use the old nexus I don’t have this issues. It only happens to the new version

And, I migrate all the data, so the same user that exists in the old nexus is in the new one and you can login with those credentials.

I have checked `nexus.log`, `request.log` and Jenkins logs but didn't find any errors.

Jenkins and "old nexus" are installed in docker form in the same server
"New nexus" is installed in another server, also as a container.

From the servers I have network connectivity between them (can ping them, check port, and curl to the URLs.

---

I have given nx-admin role to the user that is configured.
Still the same error.

While the Jenkins job was running, I left the Nexus Log Viewer open

There was no error or sign in the Nexus Log Viewer.

BUT, I managed to find the following log in Jenkins: `JENKINS_HOME/.npm/_logs/timestamp-debug.log`

Where I have the ERR 403, and got the following

```
jenkins@hostname:~/.npm/_logs$ cat timestamp-debug.log  
0 info it worked if it ends with ok  
1 verbose cli [ '/var/jenkins_home/tools  /jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/bin/node',  
1 verbose cli   '/var/jenkins_home/tools  /jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/bin/npm',  
1 verbose cli   'i' ]  
2 info using npm@5.6.0  
3 info using node@v8.9.4  
4 verbose npm-session 609c979f77769373  
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles  
6 silly preinstall api-docs@1.0.0  
7 info lifecycle api-docs@1.0.0~preinstall: api-docs@1.0.0  
8 silly install loadCurrentTree  
9 silly install readLocalPackageData  
10 silly install loadIdealTree  
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree  
12 silly install loadShrinkwrap  
13 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree  
14 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/express 2096ms  
15 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for express@^4.16.3 403 Forbidden: express@^4.16.3  
16 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/http-server 2094ms  
17 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/swagger-ui-express 2092ms  
18 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for http-server@^0.11.1 403 Forbidden: http-server@^0.11.1  
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for swagger-ui-express@^4.0.1 403 Forbidden: swagger-ui-express@^4.0.1  
20 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/multi-file-swagger 2095ms  
21 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for multi-file-swagger@2.2.0 403 Forbidden: multi-file-swagger@2.2.0  
22 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/express 45ms  
23 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for express@^4.16.3 403 Forbidden: express@^4.16.3  
24 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/http-server 46ms  
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for http-server@^0.11.1 403 Forbidden: http-server@^0.11.1  
26 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/multi-file-swagger 48ms  
27 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for multi-file-swagger@2.2.0 403 Forbidden: multi-file-swagger@2.2.0  
28 http fetch GET 403 http://nexus-url/repository/my-repo-npm/swagger-ui-express 49ms  
29 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for swagger-ui-express@^4.0.1 403 Forbidden: swagger-ui-express@^4.0.1  
30 silly saveTree api-docs@1.0.0  
31 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden: express@^4.16.3  
31 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/var/jenkins_home/tools  /jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
31 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)  
31 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)   
31 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)  
31 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)  
31 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)  
31 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)  
31 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)  
31 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)  
31 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)  
31 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)  
31 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)  
32 verbose cwd /var/jenkins_home/jobs/CUSTOM/workspace  
33 verbose Linux 4.4.21-69-default  
34 verbose argv "/var/jenkins_home/tools  /jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/bin/node" "/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_8.9.4/bin/npm" "i"
35 verbose node v8.9.4  
36 verbose npm  v5.6.0  
37 error code E403  
38 error 403 Forbidden: express@^4.16.3  
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I looked for this packages on my Nexus Repo

```
express@^4.16.3
http-server@^0.11.1
swagger-ui-express@^4.0.1
multi-file-swagger@2.2.0
```

And found that I did not got some of those, so I downloaded them and uploaded to the repo.

I have also rerun the job, but still got the same error.

Comment: `I also checked if the package (in this case express@^4.16.3) exists on Nexus, and it does.` <= in nexus3, by default, most release repos are configured with a deployment policy of "Disable redeploy" so that you cannot overwrite an existing published release. In this case you get an error when trying to redeploy (and I would bet a case of champagne it is a 403). This can be changed in your repo configuration to "Allow redeploy" if you need (although not really recommended for a public/internal release repo). A quick confirmation would be to simply delete the package before publishing again.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator
Thanks for your reply. I checked the repo, and it has the option for **Allow redeploy** already configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even configuring the proxy at server and container level didn't worked.
I'd found out that Jenkins has a proxy configuration at the application level.

So I went into Jenkins, Administration section and configured the proxy properly. After that was done, it all started to work.